# python re find string that may contain brackets

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to search for a string that may contain brackets or other characters that may not be interpreted as plain strings.

```
def findstring(string, text):
    match = re.search(string, text)
```

I do not control the string as it is derived from another module. My problem is that the string may contain **"xyz)"**, which raises an error telling me that there are unmatched brackets.

I already tried this without success

```
match = re.search(r'%s' % string, text)
```

Comment: Why are you using regex at all? If the string is supposed to be a regex, you should treat invalid regex's like 'xyz)' as errors. If its not supposted to be a regex, just use `text.find(string)` and skip the regex module completely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape the string:

```
match = re.search(re.escape(string), text)
```

From docs:

> Return string with all non-alphanumerics backslashed; this is useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it.